# use 2 class by only calling a single class

Tags: oop, coding-style

```
class merged(){


//i want to be able to use class sample1 and sample2 by just calling this merged class
} 

class sample1(){}
class sample2(){}
```

Or doing this isnt ideal? can you please suggest how can I implement this more efficiently?

Comment: Java and C# are two different languages. Pick one. You could use OOP and make class merged extend/implement both classes.

Comment: @Sanchit - Not in Java. No multiple inheritance allowed.

Comment: Use interfaces. And please don't tag the question as both Java and C#.

Comment: Take a look at [`Composite design pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Comment: @PM77-1 True, extend one class, implement the other (by making it an interface) or double implement. There are ways to somewhat work around this though not entirely ideal in some cases. That composite design pattern linked above is how I'd do it.

Comment: Not sure what you are actually trying to accomplish, but you can instantiate both "sample" classes inside `merged` and thus get access to their methods.

Comment: @Sanchit tagged it as java and c# because i do program in both, so once i got the idea for one of them i can use it to the other

Comment: @nickecarlo i tagged it as java and c# because i do program in both, so once i got the idea for one of them i can use it to the other

Comment: @sclang This isn't allowed on Stack Overflow.  Technically, since this isn't a specific language question it shouldn't be tagged with either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Composition?

```
Class merged(){

sample1 s1 = new sample1();
sample1 s2 = new sample2();

void doSomething1()
{
s1.dosomething();
}

void doSomething2()
{
s2.dosomething();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go one of the ways (or a mixture of a couple of ways) as shown below (Note: Java convention is to have the first letter of class names capital):

```
public interface Sample1() {
     // abstract methods
}

public class Sample2() {
     // whatever
}

public class Merged() extends Sample2 implements Sample1 {
     // whatever
}
```

**OR**

```
public class Sample1() {
     // abstract methods
}

public class Sample2() {
     // whatever
}

public class Merged() {
     Sample1 ob = new Sample1();
     Sample2 ob2 = new Sample2();
}
```

**OR**

```
public interface Sample1() {
     // abstract methods
}

public abstract Sample2() {
     // abstract and other methods
}

public class Merged() extends Sample2 implements Sample1 {
     // whatever
}
```

**OR**

```
public interface Sample1() {
     // abstract methods
}

public interface Sample2() {
     // abstract methods
}

public class Merged() implements Sample1, Sample1 {
     // whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this with interfaces. Modern Object-Oriented programming languages don't support multiple inheritance (believe me, it's a good thing that they don't) so you need to fix this by using interfaces.

Here's an example in Java:

```
public interface GasolineUser {
    public double getGasolineGallonsLeft();
}

public interface MusicPlayer {
    public void playMusic();
}

public class Car implements GasolineUser, MusicPlayer {
    public double getGasolineGallonsLeft(){
        // return gallons left
    }

    public void playMusic(){
        // play music
    }
}
```

Note that `Car` in this case is both a `GasolineUser` AND a `MusicPlayer`, so it can be passed to any method that requires one or any method that requires the other. Similar inheritance exists in C#. For more information on the usefulness of interfaces, do a google search on OOP Interfaces.